# what is the error in this java code?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter ur name");
        String name=input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter ur gpa");
        double gpa=input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Hi"+name+",ur gpa is "+ gpa);
       }
   }
```

---

*I am getting Following Exception:*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at    
java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909) at 
java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530) at 
java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456) at Hello.main(Hello.java:12)
```

Comment: i always get this error

i always get this error

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
 at Hello.main(Hello.java:12)

Comment: Put it in the question. Not in the comments. Also, -1 for zero evidence of research and attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: What did I just tell you? *Put the error in the **question**. Not in the comments*. I'd -1 again if I could for that.

Comment: @user3764175: What did you type in when the console prompted "enter ur gpa"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would work just fine f proper values were passed as expected by the program i.e string and then double. You  may want to add Exception handling for it

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = "";
    double gpa = 0;
    boolean correctNameEnetered = false;
    boolean correctGPAEneterd  = false;

    while(true){
         try {
             if(!correctNameEnetered){
                 System.out.println("Enter ur name");
                 name=input.nextLine();
                 correctNameEnetered = true;
             }
         }catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Please provide String value for name");
            continue;
         }
         try {
             if(!correctGPAEneterd) {
                System.out.println("enter ur gpa");
                gpa = Double.parseDouble(input.next()); 
                correctGPAEneterd = true;
             }
         }catch(NumberFormatException  ex) {
            System.out.println("Please provide an integer or decimal value for gpa");
            continue;
         }
         break;

    }

    System.out.println("Hi"+name+",ur gpa is "+ gpa);
```

Comment: when i run this code it doesn't showed a statement as "Please provide String value for name" when i typed an interger for name

Comment: That is because integer value is accepted as a String. So `1` may not be someones name is real life but as far as java is considered it is a perfectly valid String.

Comment: so what should be the solution to show that statement

Comment: Java does not provide any such functionality. You may have to write your own parse method `boolean isName(String name)` and thenin this method check whether it is a integer or long etc or other validations u may have like name should not contain integer value. If it does return false and manually thow InputMismatchException if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if you enter something other than a double as input. It's expecting a double; maybe you typed a string or something like that.

(an integer would upcast)

Comment: no problem :), still i would like to know why i got downvoted hahah

Comment: @EdwardM.B., answers to bad questions that are not incredibly good are sometimes downvoted to discourage people from answering bad questions.

Comment: And an integer is not "upcast" in this context; the syntax for double input here allows a bare integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code look fine , that exception occur when you enter for example string in except double , So to solve this problem you need to catch that's exception:

```
 try {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter ur name");
        String name=input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter ur gpa");
        double gpa=input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Hi"+name+",ur gpa is "+ gpa);
    }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```